# Show that $\{m\in X:f(m)\ge g(m) \}$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Show that if $f$ and $g$ are two (extended) measurable functions over ($X,\sigma(X),\mu$), then $\{m\in X:f(m)\ge g(m) \}$ is measurable.

I know that in order to have $f:X\rightarrow \Bbb R \bigcup \{\infty,-\infty \}$ as a measurable function, {$x: f(x)\gt \alpha$} $\in \sigma(x)$
 for all $\alpha \in \Bbb R$. I also know how to prove $af+bg,fg$ ($a,b \in \Bbb R$) and so on are measurable, but not sure how to prove the above condition. Could someone provide a proof please? Thanks.

Comment: You can separate the values of $m$ for which subtraction is a problem (ie they're both the same signed infinity) which is a measurable set and then union the set $\{f(m)-g(m)\geq0\}$ which is also measurable.

Comment: $f-g$ is a measurable function and $[0,\infty)$ is a measurable set.

Comment: ^ I meant $[0,\infty]$, not $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Forgot to mention that $f-g$ is not well-defined in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\{m \in X : f(m) \geq g(m)\} = \bigcap_{q\in \mathbb{Q}}(\{m \in X: f(m) \geq q\} \cup \{m \in X: q \geq g(m)\}).$$

As a countable intersection of finite unions of measurable sets, this set is also measurable.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee The union operation is definitely on purpose and not a typo. You'll find that in this case the RHS does actually contain the case $f(m) = g(m) = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You are right. I must have lost my mind to think that your answer is wrong. Sorry and (+1)!

Comment: Is it ok to prove $\{m \in X : f(m) \lt g(m)\}$ is measurable first, and then take the complement so that $\{m \in X : f(m) \ge g(m)\}$ is also measurable?

Comment: @user3029 Your first proposed correction does not work, since it does not cover cases where $f(m) = g(m) \notin \mathbb{Q}$. The proof you came across works though, it is basically just the complement of my proof. It's up to you whether you want to take the complement of the proof or the complement of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$ \phi(x,y) = \begin{cases}x - y &\text{ if } x \geq y \\ 0 &\text{ if } x = \infty \lor y = -\infty \\ -1 &\text{ if } x = -\infty \land y =\infty \end{cases}
$$
Then $S = \{x \in X\mid f(x) \geq g(x)\} = \{x \in X\mid \phi(f(x),g(x)) \geq 0\}$.

It remains to prove that $\phi$ is $(\sigma(X)^2,\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}))$-measurable.

To show this, you can use the fact that for any measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$, $f:X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is measurable if and only if $f^{-1}[\{\pm\infty\}] \in \Sigma$ and $f$ is measurable on $f^{-1}[\mathbb{R}]$. The latter is implied by continuity.